# React router is just showing a blank page after I structure like the şmage below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

[This is app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dISAr.png)

As result I just see a white page. I don't see any errors or anything.

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: Please edit your question to post an formatted and readable code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

The `Route` component API's `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. `Buy` should be rendered as JSX, not passed as a reference to the component.

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Buy />} />
```